# Change background color of lists in iOS15

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, ios15

With the new XCode 13 and it‘s iOS 15 support the presentation of Lists have apparently changed.
Now a List has an additional gray background. Before, the background was plain white, just as I would like it to be. When I add other elements like texts, the default background color is still white.

Is there any way to get rid of the gray surrounding of the List without switching to a `ForEach()` solution?

I tried changing the background color from gray to white on various places and adding additional stacks in hope to override the default background color.

This I want be be all white without the gray surrounding:

[image: Example Image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Test")
            
            List {
                ForEach(1..<20) { i in
                    Text(String(i))
                }         
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)                
        }       
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change the `listStyle` to `.plain`. The default for iOS 14 is `.plain`, and `.insetGrouped` for iOS 15.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test")

            List {
                ForEach(1 ..< 20) { i in
                    Text(String(i))
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Good god this hurt, thank you for clarifying the painful default change.  Dark/Light mode defaults on iOS15 are a hellish nightmare.  Live and learn... ty.